# Read XML to Java map container

Tags: java, xml, hashmap

Tneed help to read XML content in following format to the Java Map container.
(Java beginner question)

```
<Tests xmlns="http://...managerxml">      
<Test id="10500510001">
        <StaticData>
        <systemID>sysid</systemID>
        <failureSeverity>0</failureSeverity>
        <destination>5</destination>
        <ServiceMessage>
                <classA_message>CLASSA_ID_10500510001</classA_message>
                <classM_message>CLASSM_ID_10500510001</classM_message>
                <classC_message></classC_message>
         </ServiceMessage>
         <userMessage></userMessage>
        </StaticData>
    </Test>
```

I understand how to access the test id for all Tests from the list , but don't get how to access the Static Data sub -node and  attributes for each Test Node. 
Need to structure the attributes together with test id to the map of structures:
Map. Thanks in advance for your help!!

This is what I have so far:

```
File fXmlFile = new File("TestManager.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);        
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

System.out.println("Root element :" +doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Test");

System.out.println("----------------------------");

for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
    System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
        System.out.println("Indicator id : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
    }
}
```

Comment: `Indicator` does not appear in your XML sample... please correct your post for consistency.

Comment: Thanks , it should be "Test" instead of the Indicator.